# Add where condition with left join

Tags: mysql

pretty basic question here. but I am stuck with where conditions, knowing that I have multiple left joins and create a sub table w.

Here is the mysql

```
with w as (SELECT t1.c1, count(DISTINCT(t3.c3)) w from t1
left join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c2
left join t3 on t3.c3 = t2.c3
left join t4 on t4.c4 and t3.c4

where t1.c4 is true
AND t4.c5 NOT ILIKE '%XXX%'
AND t4.c5 > 0


group by 1)

SELECT
w,
count(id)

from w

group by 1
order by 1 ASC
```

Can you help me understand where to properly put the 3 conditions and how it would change the result depending on where I put them?

Cheers,

Jeff

Comment: Way too broad. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

When you have a query like

```
...
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

you get every row from `a`, no matter if there is a corresponding row in `b`. When there is no corresponding row in `b` the value is `NULL`. Therefore when you have a query like

```
...
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE b.foo = 'bar'
```

you implicitly say `WHERE b.foo IS NOT NULL`, which turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, which basically also filters table `a`.

There's two ways to fix this. The not so pretty way is of course

```
WHERE (b.foo = 'bar' OR b.foo IS NULL)
```

The more elegant way is to put the condition in the join as well.

```
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND b.foo = 'bar'
```

This way you still get every row from `a` but only the rows from `b` where all conditions apply.

Is it clear now?

Comment: Exactly, you have your opinion, I have mine (and I think that having the conditions in the join is more readable for me)

Comment: thanks you @fancyPants for the response. really helpful